# Automatic wrapping of a \multicolumn table cell

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I output lots of tables to LaTeX using the `estout`/`esttab` package in **Stata**.  I frequently want to have long footnotes on the bottom of the table, explaining coefficients, sources, etc.  The estout package inserts footnotes using `\multicolumn{#}{l}{...}` at the bottom of the table, but requires me to figure out line breaks. That is, it will print several rows of `\multicolumn{#}{l}{...} \\`, but I have to tell estout what I want on each row.  This is a pain.

I would like to find a way to make a `\multicolumn` wrap at the length of the table.  I know that I can make `\multicolumn` wrap using the `p{<width>}` alignment specifier, but all the width macros I've been able to come up with (`\hsize`, `\textwidth`, `\linewidth`, etc.) cause the `\multicolumn` to wrap at the width of the page (or whatever fixed fraction I tell it), thus either stretching out my table or wrapping too short.

Basically I want LaTeX to set the table width automatically (no `tabular*` or `tabularx`), but ignore the `\multicolumn` for the purposes of setting the width of the table, but have the `\multicolumn` wrap at the full width of the table.

Here's an example of the type of table I'm working with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{This is a table}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}c}\toprule
& Something & Something & Something & Something & Something & Something \\\midrule
Amazing regression results & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 \\\bottomrule
\multicolumn{7}{p{\textwidth}}{This is a footnote that's really really  really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really long}\\ %Ideally this should wrap without distorting the table
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Any thoughts? I feel like there must be some LaTeX parameter containing the width of the table.

Comment: How can I use \tiny also? I want "Comm. Vol." to be in two lines and very small. These are OK: `\multicolumn{2}{>{\tiny}c}{{ Comm. Vol.}}` and `\multicolumn{2}{p{.1cm}}{{ Comm. Vol.}}` But I cannot combine both.

Comment: Just a short comment. I had exactly the same problem, and I am happy to find someone that already asked it.

Even `tabu` package (version 2.8) does not handle *long* multicolumns (it is a to-do task, see section 10 in the `tabu` manual).

However, I think the final solution for this issue is too complicated for me. I will keep on creating several multicolumn rows, as I do not happen to have many of these tables.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Werner's answer is really close to what I needed, but I figured out a more streamlined way to do it that (sort of) avoids the duplication: The `\multicolumn` is set to be `\linewidth`, which is initially re-set to be really small.  The whole tabular environment (with the \multicolumn) is then put into a macro.  The macro is then put in a `\setbox`, `\linewidth` is reset to the width of the box, and then the table is printed as a macro.  Like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{This is a table}
\setlength{\linewidth}{.1cm}\newcommand{\contents}{\begin{tabular}{l*{4}c}\toprule
& Something & Something & Something & Something  \\\midrule
Amazing regression results & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100  \\\bottomrule
\multicolumn{5}{p{\linewidth}}{This is a footnote that's really really  really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really long}\\ %Ideally this should wrap without distorting the table
\end{tabular}}
\setbox0=\hbox{\contents}
\setlength{\linewidth}{\wd0-2\tabcolsep-.25em}
\contents
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

It's a similar idea to Werner's answer, in that the table is first set in a box that is not printed, and the size of the box is used to set the `\multicolumn`.  But this way while the table is technically duplicated from the perspective of the compiler, you don't have to duplicate the source code, and it's easier to put together (and to output from Stata, my goal here), since you're really just surrounding the tabular environment with a few commands.

**Update 11/16**

Since I wrote this post there have been a couple other answers regarding the Stata implementation of this wrapper approach.  My approach (devised back when I wrote the question and answer) addresses the concerns BeingQuisitive and grossdpg mention, while preserving most of the functionality of the estout options.  Specifically, I use the `substitute()` option on estout/esttab, which replaces a given string in the LaTeX output with another.  Doing it this way rather than using `postfoot()` and `prehead()` allows you to employ the various estout options that add content to those areas, without having to set them manually (including e.g. `title()` and `longtable()`).  Example Stata code:

```
#delimit ;
esttab * using output.tex, replace booktabs 
substitute(\begin{tabular} \setlength{\linewidth}{.1cm}\newcommand{\contents}{\begin{tabular}
           \end{tabular} \end{tabular}}\setbox0=\hbox{\contents}\setlength{\linewidth}{\wd0-2\tabcolsep-.25em}\contents
           {l}{\footnotesize {p{\linewidth}}{\footnotesize )
addnote{"This is a footnote that's really really  really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really long")
;
```

Note: I seem to recall that the default for `substitute()` replaces _ and $ with _ and \$, respectively.  If you need this, simply add that to the substitute option.

Answer (score 8):

LaTeX does not typeset the contents of `tabular` (or `array`) on a row-by-row basis. The obvious reason for this is that columns should line up (otherwise they won't be referred to as columns...). And, the only way of lining these up properly is if you - the LaTeX compiler - could see the entire table. So, here's my suggestion...

Store an entire copy of the table *without* the `\multicolumn` row in a box. Then, use the width of the box to set the width in your `\multicolumn{<#>}{p<width>}{...}` column. Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{This is a table}
  \setbox0=\hbox{% Store table in box0
    \begin{tabular}{l*{6}c}
      \toprule
      & Something & Something & Something & Something & Something & Something \\\midrule
      Amazing regression results & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 \\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  %}
  \begin{tabular}{l*{6}c}\toprule
    & Something & Something & Something & Something & Something & Something \\\midrule
    Amazing regression results & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 \\\bottomrule
    \multicolumn{7}{p{\wd0-2\tabcolsep-.25em}}{This is a footnote that's really really 
    really really really really really really really really really really really 
    really really really really really really really really really really really 
    really really really really really really really really really really really 
    really really really really really really really really really really really 
    really really really really really really really really really really really 
    really really really really really really really really really really really 
    really really really really really really really really really really really 
    really really really really really really really really long} %Ideally this should wrap without distorting the table
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

In the above document, the [`geometry` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) was loaded merely to change the page orientation to `landscape` since your MWE didn't fit on a portrait page. The [`calc` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc) is used to perform infix length calculations - the argument to the `p` column specification: `\wd0-2\tabcolsep-.25em` which takes the width of box 0 `\wd0`, subtracts 2 times `\tabcolsep` and also `.25em`. The last dimension comes from additional space necessarily inserted by [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs)'s rules.

[image: Booktabs with multicol stretching entire table width]

I don't see a way around the "duplication" of the table due to the way LaTeX typesets tables. Of course, `tabular*` and `tabularx` environments would be ideal (due to it's width specification in the definition), but that's out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

To put the solution by rsandler into an automated setup, one would have the following Stata code:

```
*Estimate and Store results
local PostFootTxt "\hline\hline \multicolumn{@span}{p{\linewidth}}{\footnotesize @note}\\ \end{tabular}}"
local TblMainTxt = "This is a footnote that's really really really " + ///  
  "really really really really really really really really really " + ///
  "really really really really really long"
esttab stored_results_names using filename.tex, note("`TblMainTxt'") postfoot(`PostFootTxt')
```

And then the LaTeX (or similar LyX) file would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{This is a table}
\setlength{\linewidth}{.1cm}\newcommand{\contents}{\input{filename.tex}}
\setbox0=\hbox{\contents}
\setlength{\linewidth}{\wd0-2\tabcolsep-.25em}
\contents
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**: If you have multiple tables then you can add a `\let\contents\undefined` line after the `\contents` line.

Answer (score 1):

A few more notes on the automated solution suggested by BeingQuisitive:

For this to work you can't use the title() or longtable options in the estout/esttab command, as they impose LaTeX table or longtable environments that interfere with rsandler's wrapper.

Also, as I've learned the hard way, there's a 502-character limit to footnotes for older versions (before v3.19). The reason was actually annotated in Ben Jann's estout.ado program: the estout code used the -:subinstr- macro function to substitute the text you provide in the note() option into the @note placeholder in postfoot(). This macro function has that 502-character limit, for some reason. If your footnote is too long the @note wasn't replaced, and "@note" (literal) was the text that will show up in your footnote.

The exact place in estout.ado where this came up was on line 3339 (in v3.13 at least):

```
capt local value: subinstr local value "@`atvar'" `"`macval(`atvar')'"', all
// note: returns error if length of <to> is more than 502 characters
```

Ben Jann (the author of estout) also discussed the issue on Statalist here:
http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2007-02/msg00581.html